# Btrieve without Pervasive?

Tags: c#, python, btrieve

Is there any library available to query Btrieve databases without buying something from Pervasive? I'm looking to code in C# or Python.

Comment: What version is the BTrieve database you are trying to access?  What version are the data files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible. It is not an open source database, so writing drivers for it is really hard.

Answer (score 2):

If you download one of the trial versions, you can get/install the odbc client and connect that way.

In our version of pervasive (older version) on the server where the database is installed, you can also find this client install.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the version of Btrieve. I've been working with btrieve for a long time and have found that the best API for the old 6.15 version was in pascal. That having been said there was definately a C api around as well.

Pervasive have recently released a 6.15 ultimate patch. Using this and the C api should allow you to work effectively with older btrieve databases. It is possible for instance to build new modules for python using C.